# Database design for voting

Tags: database, voting, voting-system

I am implementing a voting feature to allow users to vote for their favourite images. They are able to vote for only 3 images. Nothing more or less. Therefore, I am using checkboxes to do validation for it. I need to store these votes in my database.

Here is what i have so far :

|voteID | name| emailAddress| ICNo |imageID

(where imageID is a foreign key to the Images table)

I'm still learning about database systems and I feel like this isn't a good database design  considering some of the fields like email address and IC Number have to be repeated.

For example,

```
|voteID | name|   emailAddress     |   ICNo      |  imageID
   1      BG    email@example.com    G822A28A          10
   2      BG    email@example.com    G822A28A          11
   3      BG    email@example.com    G822A28A          12
   4      MO    email2@example.com   G111283Z          10
```

Comment: Your feeling is correct. http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/table-relationships/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have three "things" in your system - images, people, and votes.

An image can have multiple votes (from different people), and a person can have multiple votes (for different images).

One way to represent this in a diagram is as follows:

[image: Object relationships]

So you store information about a person in one place (the Person table), about Images in one place (the Images table), and Votes in one place. The "chicken feet" relationships between them show that one person can have many votes, and one image can have many votes. ("Many" meaning "more than one").